# How to automatically reconnect to mongodb after connection loss?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to figure out how I can make my nodejs/express app to automatically reconnect to mongodb after a connection loss. I've noticed that my app loses the connection when I pause/stop my mongodb cluster and never recconnect even when I enable back the cluster. Therefore I need to manually restart my app in order to re-connect to mongodb. It's not ideal for a production environment.

After some researches, I've tried to setup my connection like this :

```
const options = {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
            autoIndex: true,
            autoReconnect:true,
            reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
            reconnectInterval: 500,
            bufferMaxEntries: 0,
            connectTimeoutMS: 10000,
            socketTimeoutMS: 45000,
        }

  mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI, options);
```

But I get the following errors :

```
(node:21749) DeprecationWarning: The option `autoReconnect` is incompatible with the unified topology, please read more by visiting http://bit. ly/2D8WfT6
...
(node:21749) DeprecationWarning: The option `reconnectTries` is incompatible with the unified topology, please read more by visiting http://bit. ly/2D8WfT6
...
(node:21749) DeprecationWarning: The option `reconnectInterval` is incompatible with the unified topology, please read more by visiting http://bit. ly/2D8WfT6
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: MongoDB deprecated old topology and introduced new one (from v4.0 nodejs mongodb native driver, they made this as default topology so you don't need to add this). Now `autoReconnect`, `reconnectTries`, `reconnectInterval` are deprecated.

So you need to remove them and long story short, they have removed retry from native mongodb driver itself. Developer has to make provision of it or use lib such as mongoose. I know this is insane move and they have not mentioned it anywhere.

Comment: So If you want to make your code work remove `useUnifiedTopology` and you are good to go. BUT new version of driver does NOT support it so change it accordingly.